# Finite objects for which isomorphism is NP-hard or harder?

Tags: reference-request, computational-complexity, isomorphism-testing

Are there finite objects for which deciding isomorphism
is NP-hard or harder?

Graphs and groups are not solutions.

Searching the web didn't return answer for me.

---

Partial result based on Chow's comment.

From a [paper p.16](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mperkows/PerkowskiGoogle/drechselr-10030112.pdf)

> for IBDDs (Indexed BDDs) ... the equivalence test is coNP-complete even
>   if there are only two layers.

Indexed BDD are rooted digraphs, representing boolean function.

"Equivalence" appears very close to isomorphism and means representing the same boolean function.

Comment: Well, it can't be any kind of algebraic or relational structures, as their isomorphism reduces to GI. Topology can't help either, as it collapses on finite sets to preorder, which is again just a relation.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks. Do you mean that GI is isomorphism of finite objects complete?

Comment: I can't parse that sentence. I am saying that isomorphism of arbitrary [structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic)) is reducible to graph isomorphism.

Comment: Actually more generally: isomorphism of finite "objects" is in coAM (hence not NP-hard unless  PH = AM = coAM), as long as the standard IP protocol works (the Verifier chooses randomly one of the two given objects, randomly permutes it, and ask the Prover which object they've chosen). Basically, you only need that the objects consist of a "base set" plus whatever extra stuff, and any bijection of the base set of an object to another set lifts to an isomorphism of a uniquely determined object, poly-time computable from the given data.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Is it known that all reductions to GI take polynomial time and space in the size of the "object"? e.g. boolean propositional formula to a single clause in DNF will solve SAT.

Comment: I am of course talking about polynomial-time many-one reductions. Otherwise it wouldn't be relevant.

Comment: The following might be considered "cheating" but you can specify a graph by providing a circuit that, given the labels of two vertices, outputs 0 or 1 according to whether the vertices are adjacent or not. Deciding isomorphism for such "succinctly represented" graphs is surely NP-hard, although I'd have to think about how to prove that.

Comment: @TimothyChow Based on your comment, I edited with paper claiming that equivalence of Indexed BDDs is coNP-complete. Maybe someone will make isomorphism of this.

Comment: What you've put in the question is just an elaborate version of UNSAT. There is no point in considering a weird model like indexed BDDs when it's already coNP-complete for CNFs. Meanwhile, this has nothing to do at all with Timothy Chow's suggestion, which was the usual graph isomorphism, but for graphs represented succinctly rather than by explicit enumeration of vertices and edges.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek ok, the edit might be pointless. According to your comments Chows's approach won't work unless unlikely collapse, right?

Comment: @TimothyChow Emil's comment suggest your are looking for succinct representations of graphs. Consider "compressing" some graphs classes to BDDs as suggested in [On the OBDD size for graphs of bounded tree- and clique-width](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X08000447/pdfft?md5=4e01c56522ce457d650944f7b1bf3e7d&pid=1-s2.0-S0012365X08000447-main.pdf). From there "– for graphs of bounded tree-width there is an OBDD of size O(log n) for f G that uses encodings of size O(log n) for the vertices;"

Comment: No, that's not what I said, at all.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I added answer about NP-hardness of CIRCUIT ISOMORPHISM and FORMULA ISOMORPHISM.

Answer (score 7):

This answer consists of three parts. The first part comes closest to an actual answer, by referencing an isomorphism testing problem which is harder than graph isomorphism (but sadly not NP-hard). The second part mentions Emil Jeřábek's explanation about why isomorphism will often be in coAM, and how broadly it applies (thereby preventing most natural isomorphism testing problems from being NP-hard). The third part finally mentions some NP-hard equivalence test problems (like the IBDD problem mentioned in the question). It calls them *distinction problems*, which better captures their real nature (that is different from isomorphism testing problems). The link between these three parts is the role of input encoding and compression, especially if a canonical compression (like the straight line program representation) exists.

---

1.
 This question reminds me of [how annoyed I was about an *unexpected* definition of the ring isomorphism problem by Kayal and Saxena](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16275/natural-candidates-for-the-hierarchy-inside-npi/16279#comment66578_16279):

> Group Isomorphism $\leq_m$ Graph Isomorphism $\leq_m$ Ring Isomorphism. Also Integer Factoring $\leq_m$ Ring Isomorphism [[Kayal and Saxena](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2004/109/)]. Also Graph Automorphism $\leq_m$ Graph Isomorphism.

I was annoyed about Integer Factoring $\leq_m$ Ring Isomorphism, because it used a *compressed representation* for rings, and hence used an *unexpected* measure for the length of the input:

> The ring is given by addition/mult tables, but these have a canonical compressed representation for rings (because the additive group is Abelian), so the GI-completeness result for finite structures is not relevant.

Even so testing isomorphism for this example (Ring Isomorphism) isn't NP-hard, it is harder than GI, and the can of worms provided by allowing compressed input might make it possible to come up with actual examples of NP-hard isomorphism testing problems. The paper implicitly assumes that the orders $d_k$ and the coefficients $a_{ij}^k$  are encoded in binary representation. But why not use unary representation (less compressed) or straight line program representation (more compressed) instead? The straight line program representation for Abelian groups (only addition, no multiplication) is actually equivalent to binary encoding, so using binary encoding might be indeed justified as a canonical compression here.

---

2.
Emil Jeřábek's comment about isomorphism being in coAM still applies even to this compressed representation (at least if you ignore the part with the base set). We can randomly select a basis, and everything else is uniquely determined from that basis, so the standard IP protocol works. (There are actually many subtleties, even beyond the proof of claim 3.1.2. $RI\in coAM$ given in the paper, but it is true nevertheless.)

<sup>I often learn more from Emil Jeřábek's comments than from the actual answers. He's probably a great teacher, and uses the comments for more interaction with the asker and more focused teaching, than would be possible by a mere static answer.</sup>

---

3.
If we allow straight line program representation as a valid compression of the input, then we can easily come up with many NP-hard equivalence test problems similar to the *indexed binary decision diagrams* problem given in the question. Asking whether two boolean formulas (given as straight line programs for the free Boolean ring, using the constants $0$, $1$, the unary minus operation, and the binary addition and multiplication operations) are distinct (non-equivalent) is actually NP-complete (and closely related to SAT). One could call this problem of distinguishing two elements of a free algebra given in straight line program representation the [*slp distinction problem*](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55413/what-is-the-name-of-the-word-problem-for-free-groups-under-straight-line-program). This problem is undecidable for the free modular lattice (on 4 or more generators). But for undecidable problems, it doesn't even matter whether we compressed the input or not, hence some people wrongly believe that it doesn't matter how the input is encoded (if it is only compressed).

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to parse this. Isn't something like mixing unitary and binary clear abuse, leading to a mess? And what is the answer to the question?

Comment: @joro I restructured the answer now into three distinct parts and an explanation about the role of those parts, to make it easier to parse. The answer to the question is that using input compression (for example generators of permutation groups) might be able to come up with hard examples of isomorphism testing problems, but even then Emil Jeřábek's comment about isomorphism being in coAM will often still apply and prevent the problem from being NP-hard.

Comment: So this is partial answer, asking more questions, right? The issue of "compressing" appears complicated, I have seen problems of the form "can something be compressed".

Comment: @joro Even if this is not a complete answer, the intention is certainly not to ask more questions. If your question is interpreted sufficiently strict, then the answer would be that there are no finite objects for which deciding isomorphism is NP-hard or harder, in the sense that the problem will always be in $AM\cap coAM$, which can only be NP-hard if the polynomial hierarchy collapses. Maybe it was a bad idea to describe the encoding by generators or by straight line programs as "compression". The issue is annoying (it is a source of disagreement), but not like "can something be compressed".

Comment: Related cryptography question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371362/can-we-make-cryptography-signature-algorithm-based-on-hardness-of-isomorphism

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is not exactly what you meant, but [isomorphism testing of succinct graphs is known to be hard for PSPACE](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2015/100/); that is, succinct graphs are ones given implicitly by a circuit $C$ where $C(u,v)=1$ iff there exists an edge $(u,v)$ in the graph. The intuition for this is the "boosting" of LOGSPACE-hardness results up to PSPACE when going to the succinct representation (since succinct graphs can be exponentially large in the size of their circuit)

Note that this result is entirely compatible with Emil's point about coAM because the isomorphism of succinct graphs is not known to be in NP (thus the standard interactive proof is not sufficient for proving nonisomorphism)

Answer (score 2):

Two candidates for NP-hardness of isomorphism are CIRCUIT ISOMORPHISM
and FORMULA ISOMORPHISM.

For CIRCUIT ISOMORPHISM [Joshua Grochow claims](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20721/how-hard-is-the-circuit-isomorphism-problem/20736#20736).

> Circuit Isomorphism is the problem: given two circuits $C_1, C_2$ on $n$ inputs, is there a permutation $\pi \in S_n$ such that $C_1(\vec{x})$ and $C_2(\pi(\vec{x}))$ are equivalent? Circuit Isomorphism has a status similar to that of Graph Isomorphism, but one level higher in $\mathsf{PH}$: it is $\mathsf{coNP}$-hard (by the same reduction above), not known to be in $\mathsf{coNP}$, in $\mathsf{\Sigma_2 P}$, but not $\mathsf{\Sigma_2 P}$-complete unless $\mathsf{PH} = \mathsf{\Sigma_3 P}$

For FORMULA ISOMORPHISM:  Michael Bauland, Edith Hemaspaandra, *Isomorphic Implication*, Theory Comput Syst (2009) 44: 117–139, doi:[10.1007/s00224-007-9038-1](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00224-007-9038-1), arXiv:[cs/0412062](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0412062), on p.1:

> The formula isomorphism problem is in $\Sigma_2^p$ , NP-hard, and unlikely to be $\Sigma_2^p$.-complete

From the abstract:

> We study the isomorphic implication problem for Boolean constraints. We show that this is a natural analog of the subgraph isomorphism problem. We prove that, depending on the set of constraints, this problem is in P, NP-complete, or NP-hard, coNP-hard, and in parallel access to NP. We show how to extend the NP-hardness and coNP-hardness to hardness for parallel access to NP for some cases, and conjecture that this can be done in all cases.

These examples appear to contradict Emil's claim that isomorphism of finite object can't be too hard.