# Can we make cryptography signature algorithm based on hardness of isomorphism?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, cryptography, isomorphism-testing

In public key cryptography, Alice knows functions $f$ and its inverse
$f^{-1}$. $f$ is public and $f^{-1}$ is secret. To sign a message
$m$, she gives $(m,a=f^{-1}(m))$. To verify a signature, the verifier
checks if $f(a)=f(f^{-1}(m)) ?= m$.

$f$ and $f^{-1}$ are related by some secret $S$ and it is computationally
infeasible an adversary to compute $f^{-1}$ or the secret $S$.

Examples of secrets $S$ are integer factorization and discrete logarithms.

One possible approach is to take the secret $S$ to be obfuscation permutation
and $f$,$f^{-1}$ to be some "objects" for which isomorphism (and the permutation $S$) is hard to compute, while still have "some properties" for signature.

The question from 2016 [Finite objects for which isomorphism is NP-hard or harder?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/238743/finite-objects-for-which-isomorphism-is-np-hard-or-harder) appears to
give hard isomorphism.

> Q Can we make cryptography signature algorithm based on hardness of isomorphism
> with security at least NP-hard?

There is related work based Isomorphism of Polynomials, but we
believe its security is only Graph Isomorphism (could be wrong on this).

NP-hardness of Hamiltonian Cycle is used in [Zero-knowledge proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof#Hamiltonian_cycle_for_a_large_graph)

**Added** 2020-09-15

From [answer the linked question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/238743/finite-objects-for-which-isomorphism-is-np-hard-or-harder/371730#371730)
two candidates for NP-hardness are CIRCUIT ISOMORPHISM
and FORMULA ISOMORPHISM.

> On p.1:  The formula isomorphism problem is in $\Sigma_2^p$ , NP-hard, and unlikely to be $\Sigma_2^p$.-complete

Comment: Crossposted at cstheory: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/47551/can-we-make-cryptography-signature-algorithm-based-on-hardness-of-isomorphism

Comment: This question seems to be asking if we can construct a trapdoor one-way function based on the hardness of some isomorphism problem (which is what $f$ appears to be), that we can use in a digital signature scheme. But it is well-known that digital signature schemes can be constructed from the weaker notion of a one-way function (note that if you were interested in public-key encryption, known techniques require trapdoor OWFs). Is your primary interest a trapdoor OWF, or a digital signature scheme?

Comment: @Mark I am mainly interested as trapdoor, which can also be used in encryption like RSA.

Comment: One candidate might be Circuit Isomorphism.

Comment: Then you should know that there are no known constructions of public-key encryption from an NP-complete problem (despite ones that get "close but barely miss", say LWE-based protocols), so if you suggest building such a thing this would be a major result independently of this specific question.

Comment: As for basing cryptography on "circuit isomorphism", I've heard some practitioners express hope on basing cryptography on the "Minimum Circuit Size Problem". This is a problem asking if a certain circuit has a "small representation" (generally in terms of some size bound). The hardness of MCSP is a rather intricate story though (and there have been *many* developments in the last 5 years), but MCSP can be thought of better as finding a "compact normal form" for circuits than of asking if two circuits are isomorphic.

Comment: @Mark Thanks. I edited with NP-hardness of FORMULA ISOMORPHISM and CIRCUIT ISOMORPHISM.

Comment: crossposted on crypto: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/84023/can-we-make-cryptography-signature-or-encryption-algorithm-based-on-hardness-of

Comment: You might be interested in this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242737/inverting-a-function

Comment: @orgesleka Interesting, thanks.